# Attachments in allure report

Tags: java, maven, selenium, allure

I have list of asserts in my selenium code. I want all the asserts and responses to be added as part of attachment for the passed test cases.

Also, I want to know is there a way to add the server logs to the attachments for the failed test cases

Please let me know...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. From Allure perspective you can add almost anything as attachment(-s) to report (please see https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/Attachments).
2. It is possible to redirect standard output/error, so log messages will come as Allure attachment. You own implementation required.
3. In Selenium case server logs are generated by separate JVM. So the method above doesn't work and you need manually fetching log files from server and attaching them to Allure.